# JQuery Post Undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, post, undefined

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. I've done a post call many times before without issues but today this one is giving me problems. I'm using asp.net MVC 3

```
 $('#CancelButton').click(function(){
        var emailUrl = $('.emailUrl').attr('id');
        $.Post('@Url.Content("~/")Offer/DeleteImage/?Url=' + emailUrl + '&imageName=' + imageName, function(data) {
        });
    });
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   '$.Post('/Offer/DeleteImage/?Url=' + emailUrl + '&imageName=' +
>   imageName, function(data) {
>           })')

And I have this in my shared layout

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Other Views have jquery working fine, but I have not used a post call on this project so maybe I'm just making a simple mistake :)

Thanks!

Comment: Don't know if it makes a difference, but do a lowercase 'p' in $.post.

Comment: Yes it does make a difference! How silly! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$.Post
```

should be

```
$.post
```

It's case sensitive.